# Will I receive Social Security outside the U.S.?

Tags: us-citizens, social-security

I recently retired and am receiving social security.  If I move out of the U.S., will I still receive my SS checks?

Comment: Why not have your SS direct-deposited into a US bank and use that bank's debit card at a foreign ATM to get cash? Much easier and safe from prying eyes in your foreign home.

Answer (score 9):

You can look at the [Your Payments while Outside US](http://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10137.pdf) from Social Security Administration.

On pages 12 and 13  of the booklet you can find the list of countries where you cannot receive the payments, which currently includes:

- Cuba
- North Korea
- Azerbaijan
- Belarus
- Georgia
- Kazakhstan
- Kyrgyzstan
- Moldova
- Tajikistan
- Turkmenistan
- Ukraine,
- Uzbekistan

There are other conditions that are spelled out in that document as well.

Comment: Interestingly, this list contains most of the post-Soviet states, but not Russia.